# How to add all of the migrations/ to git .gitignore file in django?

Tags: django, git

In my Django project, I have many migrations directory, I want to add to my .gitignore file:

Because they are under each app directory, I do not want to add every one.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

How can I add all the `migrations` directories in it?

Now in it only like this:

```
.idea/
```

Comment: Your migration directories *should* be under control. Otherwise you won't be able to run the same migrations in dev and production.

Comment: @Alasdair is right, of course. Nevertheless, in the very early stages of **local** development for a **new** project, while my models are in great flux (yes, often due to bad design, but that's another issue), and there is no production database yet, I like to `.gitignore` all migrations. Before first deployment, or before first sharing my code, or whenever it becomes really necessary, I clean my slate and create all *fresh initial migrations*. Only at that point do I un-ignore the migrations and start adding them to source control.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add "**/migrations/*" to your .gitignore file, this will add all folders and it's contents called migrations to git ignore. More informations [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: This also ignores `migrations/__init__.py`. If your apps do not have this, django (3.2) returns `No changes detected` when you run `makemigrations`.

Answer (score 21):

This is a correct:

```
**/migrations/**
!**/migrations
!**/migrations/__init__.py
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a new line in .gitignore file like so -

```
**/migrations/
```

if the `migrations` folder is multiple level deep add the same in the .gitignore like the following

```
**/**/migrations
```

Answer (score 1):

You must not do this. Migrations are part of your code base, and must be committed and deployed with it.

Comment: If not do it, whether I will get conflict ?

Comment: Where would you get a conflict? And why?

Comment: some `__pycache__/xxx.cpython-35.pyc`, should not be migrations.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. pycache is not part of your code base; migrations are.

Comment: ok, when I pull  the origin branch using master branch, I get this conflicts like so.